# Django - I am trying to add a user object to a ManyToManyField, but it keeps adding all the users objects

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

in my model.py:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    votes_total = models.ManyToManyField(Vote, related_name="votes", blank=True)
```

in my view.py:

```
def create(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    product = Product()
    product.title = request.POST['title']
    vote = Vote()
    vote.user = request.user
    vote.save()
    product.save()
    product.votes_total.add(vote)
    product.save()
    return redirect('/products/' + str(product.id))
```

So after I create a Product and go to the admin page. under votes_total for the product I created It has added all of the vote objects that have been created.
I just want the user vote added. I am not sure why it adds all of the votes that have ever been created

admin/product
Product(1)
-> votes_total = {voteObject(1),voteObject(2),voteObject(3),...}

I just want the current voteobject i sent added for that created product
Product(1)
-> votes_total = {voteObject(1)}

I thought i have a clear understanding of it but anyone know where I went wrong?

Update Solution:
I realize that the when you are in the admin panel for a manytomanyfield. it shows you all the objects that have been created and alows you to add more by selecting from the list.

Comment: Did you posted a full view function?

Comment: ya just added the render at the end.

Comment: print your vote object in the console and verify if its the same as you expect it to be

Comment: ya i think i figured it out. I printed it and it comes out as 1 like it should. When you go to the admin page it actually gives you a list of all the vote  objects and the highlighted ones are what is in the vote_total. It allows you to select from all the vote objects. Thanks.

Comment: Nice. The admin page usually gives all the objects that are available under a class for reference and allows the admin to update them if needed.

Comment: Ya, haha wow i spent along time trying to figure that out. Thanks for the heads up.